# Get checked checkboxlist data from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I created a list in view by iterating items in an session array over a loop. I even put check boxes for each iteration. I need to get the checked values as a string or an array of strings in  to controller. How can I do that. This is the view part.

```
 <?php
                $session = Yii::$app->session;
                $array = explode('\r\n', $session['cdr_val']) ;                                  
             ?>
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">CDR Configurations</h3>
                    <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-transfer"></span>', ['#'], ['data-url' => Url::toRoute(['cdr/compare']), 'id' => 'btn-compare', 'title' => 'Compare']); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="box-body">
                    <!--form class="form-horizontal" name="form_blacklist_table" id=""-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="box-body boxpad contSeperator">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <table id="analyse-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="actions-fix-wd-1 text-center">Select</th>
                                            <th>CDR</th>
                                            <th class="actions-fix-wd-2 text-center">Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                         <?php if ($array[0]!=''){ ?>
                                        <?php $j = 0 ?>
                                        <?php do{ ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                           <!--?=
                                           //$form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(['value' => "$j",'encode'=>false,'label'=>null]) ?-->

                                           <input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="<?= $j ?>">
                                        </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div>
                                                    <?php
                                                        echo($array["$j"]);
                                                        ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="text-center actions">
                                                <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>', ['#'], ['data-url' => Url::toRoute(['cdr/analyze','id'=>$array["$j"]]), 'id' => 'btn-view', 'title' => 'analyze']); ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <?php $j++ ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php }while($j<sizeof($array)); ?>
                                        <?php } ?>
```

And i used javascript part to trigger the checkboxes, And it successsfully triggered the checkbox checked values. but i couldn't any way to send it to controller.

```
$urlView1 = Url::to('cdr/compare');
$script1 = <<< JS
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-compare', function(e) {

        var items=document.getElementsByName('checkbox1');
        var selectedItems="";
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true){
                selectedItems+=","+items[i].value;
            }
        }
        //console.log("{$urlView1}")

        /*$.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=cdr/compare",
            type : 'post',
            data: 'items=' + selectedItems,
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $('#view-comp').attr("src", $(this).attr('data-url'));
                $('#ViewModal').modal({show:true})
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
            },
        });*/
        $('#view-comp').attr("src", $(this).attr('data-url'));
        $('#ViewComp').modal({show:true})
        return false;            
});
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script1);
```

here is the necessary controller part

```
public function actionCompare(){
$model = new CdrAllinone();
        $session = Yii::$app->session;
        $this->layout = 'popup';
        print_r(Yii::$app->request->getUrl());
print_r($_POST);
```

And model has the variables defined and returned.

Comment: And i'd really like to know if there is a way to transfer selectedItems variable in js part to controller. at least how to attach it to url

Comment: It is done by using `get` method in request.

Comment: It does not get the value. maybe when a popup called, data in the variable gets cleared idk. always gives NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        ...
        <?php if (!empty($array[0])): ?>
        <?php foreach($array as $key => $value): ?>
            <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <!--?=
                    //$form->field($model, 'status[]')->checkbox(['value' => "$key",'encode'=>false,'label'=>null]) ?-->

                    <input name="checkbox1[]" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="<?= $key ?>">
                </td>
                    <td>
                <div>
                        <?= $value ?>
                </div>
                    </td>

                <td class="text-center actions">
                    <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>', ['#'], ['data-url' => Url::toRoute(['cdr/analyze','id'=> $value]), 'id' => 'btn-view', 'title' => 'analyze']); ?>
                </td>          
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        ...
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: still didn't work. the submit button i used for checkbox is at top outside the loop. Plus the js variable selecteditems got the value i want. i don't know how to transfer it to controller.post method always print out as null

Comment: @Sandeepa Kariyawasam post this in your controller `return \Yii::$app->request->post("items")`, and comment everything else.

Comment: the value has printed as NULL.despite whatever checkbox i clicked. console shows the selected value. Is there anyway i can attach the value to url and get it from controller?

Comment: @Sandeepa Kariyawasam Try this `data : { items : selectedItems },`

Comment: Still the output gives NULL.console log shows the checked data correctly so issue won't be there.

Comment: Check in browser console that request has been sent, and put in controller `return "OK";`

Comment: var_dump(isset(Yii::$app->request));    bool(true)

Comment: but  var_dump(isset(Yii::$app->request->post)); bool(false)

Comment: What response do you have in console? on ajax call?

Comment: post('items') show the value in console. but it didn't print out in controller.